# Safari doesn't send form data to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, safari

I've facing the problem, all browsers except Safari send the form to email. With Chrome everything works well, but Safari on the *laptop and i Phones doesn't send anything*. Only sometimes after clearing the cache. Maybe you know how to fix it?
Moreover on server I've got logs ( ASCII text, with very long lines )

```js
$('#form-order').submit(function() { 
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
    eraseCookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "data/order.php", 
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
    }
})});
```

```html
<form id="form-order" name="order-form">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="name">Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="user-name"required id="name" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
         <input type="text" name="user-surname" id="surname" >
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">  
         <label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
         <input type="tel" name="phone-number" placeholder="+375291111111" required  id="phone" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">  
         <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
         <input type="email" name="user-email" placeholder="mail@mail.com" id="email">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

```
    $to = "sohoflowersby@gmail.com";  

    $subject = 'Форма приема заказа'; 
    $message = '
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                    <p>Name: '.$_POST['user-name'].'</p>
                    <p>Surname: '.$_POST['user-surname'].'</p>
                    <p>Phone: '.$_POST['phone-number'].'</p>
                    <p>Email: '.$_POST['user-email'].'</p>

                </body>
            </html>'; 

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: Отправитель <sohoflowersby@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

Comment: Those server logs would definitely be helpful. Additionally, if you could try submitting it in Safari and see if there are any errors in Safari's JavaScript console, that would also be very useful ([here's a tutorial if you don't know how to access the JS console](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/)). I'm also a bit confused by your code sample: it looks like you have PHP code but there is no opening `<?php` line -- it starts in the middle of some JS code.

Comment: I don't see any `<?php` tag mentioned, no `<script>` tag for your ajax request. Are using same code in file that you posted here?

Comment: try using jQuery validation plugin.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @JigneshBhavani I just cut them off to paste here. All the code is in 3 files (js/php/html)